# how to get an answer? (no page reload)

Tags: javascript, json, express, handlebars.js

the server sends a response. I don't understand how to process it. If you get "json" opens a page with array. If you get "res.render" refreshes the page. How can I get json and process it.

```js
// express.js

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {          
    if (errors.array().find(el => el.param === 'login')) {
        //1 version
        res.status(409).json({
            message: 'Error login'
        })
        //2 version
        res.render('reg', {
            isReg: true
        })
    } 
}
```

```html
 
 <!-- Handlebars -->
 <form class="login-form" action="/reg" method="POST" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="text-uppercase">Login</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationLogin" name="login" placeholder="" required>
    </div>
        <div class="block-login d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login float-right">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- how to get an answer?  -->

<script>
//example
var answer = res.json
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `res.json` then the end point will return JSON. This is designed to be consumed with some custom code and not by being loaded directly into the browser. You could make an [Ajax request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and then insert data from the result into the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents). This is how you get the result without loading a new page.

If you use `res.render` then then end point will return whatever you render, which is almost always HTML. This **is** a new page. You are expected to pass the data as the second argument to `render` and then process it with the view engine you have selected (handlebars in this case).

e.g.

```
<p>{{isReg}}</p>
```